# How to create and autowire a collection of beans using map with properties in Spring

Tags: java, spring, properties

For example, we have this YAML settings:

```
some_setting
  group1
    param1: some value
    param2: 42
    ...
  group2
    param1: another value
    param2: 123
    ...
  ...
```

Is it possible to create beans with properties from each group of above settings and autowire it as a collection?

I can write the following class to map properties from file:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("some_setting.group1")
public class SomeSettings1 {
    ...
}
```

and then inject:

```
@Component
public class SomeComponent1 {
    @Autowired
    public SomeComponent(SomeSettings1 instance) {
        ...
    }
}
```

but in this case I need to copy @ConfigurationProperties' class and depending component for each group, what is not acceptable, of course.

In Guice it is similar to [AssistedInject](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject).